# Given three nested dictionaries, sort the top two nested dictionaries from a value in the innermost dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to sort both the outermost dictionary and the "middle" dictionary by the value of "Cal" (highest first) in the innermost dictionary. I would like to accomplish this using an OrderedDict.

Given the example below, this what I am trying to accomplish:

- For all foods, order the food subtypes by highest calorie content (i.e - For Pizza, Pesto should appear first because it has higher calories when compared to cheese.
- Order all foods by highest calorie content (i.e - Pizza should appear first as it has a subtype with more calories than any other food)

I have the following data:

```
foods =
{
    "Apple": {
        "Red": {
            "Cal": "1", 
            "Taste": "4"
        }, 
        "Green": {
            "Cal": "2", 
            "Taste": "6"       
        }
    }, 
    "Pizza": {
        "Pesto": {
            "Cal": "200", 
            "Taste": "9"
        }, 
        "Cheese": {
            "Cal": "100", 
            "Taste": "11" 
        }       
    }
}
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
d =
{
    "Pizza": {
        "Pesto": {
            "Cal": "200", 
            "Taste": "9"
        }, 
        "Cheese": {
            "Cal": "100", 
            "Taste": "11"       
        }
    }, 
    "Apple": {
        "Green": {
            "Cal": "2", 
            "Taste": "6"
        }, 
        "Red": {
            "Cal": "1", 
            "Taste": "4" 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: ...dictionaries are unordered. or is your data in an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: I have a dictionary that I would like to put in an OrderedDict

Comment: go ahead and try it! if you get stuck, come back with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Well, before I tacked on the outermost dictionary, this was working well `OrderedDict(sorted(self.outer_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Cal']))`. I am not really sure how to approach it now that there is another dictionary enclosing it all.  @hiroprotagonist

Comment: i suggest you open a new question with what you have tried.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I can't ask again for another three days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
for food, dct in sorted(foods.items(),
                        key=lambda x: max(int(y['Cal']) for y in x[1].values()),
                        reverse=True):
    od[food] = OrderedDict()
    subod = od[food]
    for subkey, subdct in sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]['Cal']),
                                 reverse=True):
        subod[subkey] = subdct
```

with your new input this gives:

```
# from pprint import pprint
# pprint(od)

OrderedDict([('Cheesecake',
              OrderedDict([('ExtraSweet', {'Cal': '18000', 'Taste': '16'}),
                           ('Sweet', {'Cal': '12000', 'Taste': '17'})])),
             ('IceCream',
              OrderedDict([('Chocolate', {'Cal': '2000', 'Taste': '9'}),
                           ('Vanilla', {'Cal': '1000', 'Taste': '11'})])),
             ('Pizza',
              OrderedDict([('Pesto', {'Cal': '200', 'Taste': '9'}),
                           ('Cheese', {'Cal': '100', 'Taste': '11'})])),
             ('Apple',
              OrderedDict([('Green', {'Cal': '20', 'Taste': '6'}),
                           ('Red', {'Cal': '1', 'Taste': '4'})]))])
```

(but please: for your next question take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: thank you for answering the question. I will follow the tour prior to asking my next question. Unfortunately, the solution provided only sorts the inner food types for each food, but not the food itself. I've tested this by adding more foods to "d" and printing "od" immediately after running your code.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question a bit... is that better now?

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in a non-pythonic way. Here is the problem rewritten and the solution. I'd appreciate a simpler solution with explanation if anyone wants to give it a shot.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

foods = {
    "Apple": {
        "Red": {
            "Cal": "1", 
            "Taste": "4"
        }, 
        "Green": {
            "Cal": "20", 
            "Taste": "6"       
        }
    }, 
    "Pizza": {
        "Pesto": {
            "Cal": "200", 
            "Taste": "9"
        }, 
        "Cheese": {
            "Cal": "100", 
            "Taste": "11" 
        }       
    },
    "Cheesecake": {
        "Sweet": {
            "Cal": "12000", 
            "Taste": "17"
        }, 
        "ExtraSweet": {
            "Cal": "18000", 
            "Taste": "16" 
        }       
    },
    "IceCream": {
        "Chocolate": {
            "Cal": "2000", 
            "Taste": "9"
        }, 
        "Vanilla": {
            "Cal": "1000", 
            "Taste": "11" 
        }       
    }
}

foodDict = {}
foodTypeDict = {}
ary = []

# This orders the food types for each food 

for food in foods.iteritems():
    foodTypeDict[food[0]] = OrderedDict(sorted(food[1].iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Cal'],reverse=True))

# This orders the entire dictionary of food 

for food,value in foodTypeDict.iteritems():
    for a in value.iteritems():
        ary.append(a[1]['Cal'])
    foodDict[food] = float(max(ary))
    ary = []

sFoodDict = OrderedDict(sorted(foodDict.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))

# Create final dictionary with contents of former two dictionaries

for a in sFoodDict.items():
    sFoodDict[a[0]] = foodTypeDict[a[0]]

print(json.dumps(sFoodDict,indent=4))
```